# TV tuner pinout

Tags: rf, tv, ham-radio, vhf

I was looking for some old VHF/UHF TV tuners for an RF receiver experiment and stumbled upon this old tuner from a shop. It has a label showing TELE1-030A and an IC inside shows ALP008M (Terrestrial tuner IC, as per Philips discontinued product list). It is also listed on some Russian components supplier websites without much data. It has a dark brown RCA jack and 8 pins, (7 together and 1 separate). After seeing the pinouts from other tuners, I am assuming that the single isolated pin at back is IF output.

Is it possible to identify the pinout of this tuner? I searched for the IC datasheet and the tuner pinout but couldn't get much lead. In fact, this is the first time I am seeing a tuner with an RCA jack.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The RCA jack is gonna be the video signal output likely.   It is (was?) a common connector for composite video (i.e. a signal that contains video and audio information)

Comment: Should search something like this https://hackaday.com/2016/07/11/not-quite-101-uses-for-an-analog-uhf-tv-tuner/

Comment: @KyleB If the device is a tuner, rather than a modulator, the RCA (phono) connector will be the RF input..

Comment: The single-layer layout is impressive. It’s like air wiring in the old days. Everything surrounded by dielectric, no ground planes. A good photo!

Answer (score 1):

The pin that stands alone is not a video out signal, rather it is the intermediate frequency that is sent to the video and audio decoder strips. In the UK the IF frequency is centered on 38mhz. I too am looking into using a tuner like this for a down-convertor project. The rca is of course rf input. there will be pins for power and if the unit is an old tuner there will be an input to tune the varicap diodes (0 to 30 dc no current uAs) you might get some clues by googling the number on the IC and tracing the internal circuit. All that these tuners do is to down-convert a single frequency down to 38mhz with a bandwidth of 8 to 10 mhz using a local oscillator controlled by varicap diodes. I hope this helps a little.